# Match a string after a string is matched in multiple line

Tags: regex

I try to write a regex to search the port name with alias "USBBoard"
by using this:

> Port name=(COM\d+).*Alias=BoardUSB

But it seems the group match 'COM10' instead of 'COM1'
Any advice to improve the regex? thanks

```
[Serial_COM10]
Port name=COM10
Baud rate=9600
Data bits=8
Timeout=2500
Alias=COM_PPS
Handshake=None
[Serial_COM1]
Port name=COM1
Baud rate=9600
Data bits=8
Timeout=2500
Alias=BoardUSB
Handshake=None
[Serial_COM3]
Port name=COM3
Baud rate=115200
Data bits=8
Timeout=2500
Alias=usb_hub
Handshake=None
```

Comment: What is the regex flavor?

Comment: Where is the regex used? Try `Port name=(COM\d+)(?:(?!\[Serial_COM).)*?Alias=BoardUSB`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this pattern:

```
(?m)^Port name=(COM\d+)\r?\n(?:[^[].*\n)*Alias=BoardUSB
```

`[^[]` ensures that the lines between "Port name" and "Alias" don't start with a `[`.

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/1ZGDwp/2)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
Port\sname=(COM\d+)((?!Port)[\w\W])*Alias=BoardUSB
```

In particular, `((?!Port)[\w\W])*` excludes all strings containing the word "Port" between "Port" and "Alias", so that you don't read the Alias associated to another port.